# Using decimal numbers with systeme package

Tags: punctuation, systeme

Since different equations of are separated with a comma, it prevents me from using decimal numbers in the systems of equations.

1) I haven't found a separate LaTeX command to type a comma in math mode in order to circumvent this problem. Is there one?
2a) How to modify systeme so that I can input commas as usual?
OR
2b) How to modify systeme so that I can change the argument separator to semicolon (instead of comma)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\systeme{2x-y=\frac{3}{2},x+2y=6}
\end{document}
```

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\systeme{2x-y=1,5,x+2y=6}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare the letter, which separates the formulae with an extra optional argument: `\systeme[][:]`.  In this case, the colon is used as separator.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\systeme[][:]{2x-y=1,5:x+2y=6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That should do it! (It's not a permanent global change, but that seems to be the neatest one.)

What is the first optional argument for? I didn't interpret the original French manual...

Comment: @JoonasD6: I don't speak french, neither.  I am sorry :-(

Answer (score 4):

Using `1,5` in math mode for a decimal number is wrong, as it produces a thin space after the comma.

If you have just a few of these numbers, you can just input them like `1{,}5`. Otherwise it's best to use `siunitx` and its `\num` command.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{systeme}

% for the second solution (recommended)
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\systeme{2x-y=\frac{3}{2},x+2y=6}

\bigskip

\systeme{2x-y=1{,}5,x+2y=6}

\bigskip

\systeme{2x-y=\num{1.5},x+2y=6}

\end{document}
```

You can type `\num{1.5}` as well as `\num{1,5}` and the output will be the same.

[image]

Comment: I tend to use the icomma package for fixing the spacing. I have never got interested in siunitx package as its syntax is cumbersome; it's most often faster to just write stuff like \mathrm{\,kg} yourself because many things that regularly need little to none work need lots of commands and environments with the package. :S

But thanks a lot for the tip about {,}. It's not the cleanest solution, but it'll work in a pinch!

Comment: @JoonasD6 I'd never use `1,5` in such text, to be honest, but, instead, `3/2`.

Comment: Too bad then how I'll have to teach students to be fluent in all possible ways to express rational numbers. :)

Were this some physics application, a measurement of 1,5 would not be written as a fraction that would mask its precision.